# Convolutional networks: passing hidden layer weights as input to other model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

We built a small cnn using keras, tensorflow.
We used keras's functional API for that matter.
We're interested in passing last convolutional layer's weights (the one before the fully connected layers) as an input to other cnn.

for simplicity I suggest the next simplified code to discuss upon:

```
    from keras.utils import plot_model
    from keras.models import Model
    from keras.layers import Input
    from keras.layers import Dense
    from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
    from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
    visible = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pool2)
    output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
    model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)
    model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
            loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', None],
            metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_dataset,
        train_labels,
        epochs=400,
        batch_size=512,
        validation_data=(valid_dataset, valid_labels),
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=[early_stop])
    # summarize layers
    print(model.summary())
    # plot graph
    plot_model(model, to_file='convolutional_neural_network.png')
```

**question is: how can I pass pool2 layer as an input to some other simple model using keras, so it will train simultaniously with the first model described above?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would be to add to your model so that everything is contained in a single model that ends with 2 branches. The functional API in keras allows you to define connections between layers however you want, and also provides the infrastructure for having multiple outputs and loss functions.

For example:

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.pooling import MaxPooling2D
visible = Input(shape=(64,64,1))
conv1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(visible)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
conv2 = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(pool1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

#add your second model here 
X = FirstLayer()(pool2) #replace with your actual network layer 
# ... 
output2 = YourSecondOutput()(X) 

hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(pool2)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=[output, output2]) #list of outputs 
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
        loss=['sparse_categorical_crossentropy', None],
        metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_dataset,
    train_labels,
    epochs=400,
    batch_size=512,
    validation_data=(valid_dataset, valid_labels),
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=[early_stop])
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
# plot graph
plot_model(model, to_file='convolutional_neural_network.png')
```

Then you’ll just need to update your inputs to fit so that you have labels for each output. You can find more info in the keras documentation on [multi input and output models](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models)

Comment: Assuming the design you've suggested, this syntax: outputs=[output, output2] , ensures that each training step on model, will result in another training step on NewModel (where you've suggested to put it in)?

Comment: Yes. In this design there is a single model with multiple branches. When you train the entire model will be trained, so both branches will be trained simultaneously. Basically, you’ve merged two models into a single larger model.